# Fill linearlayout with cardviews and viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have an issue trying to fill a linear layout with cardviews inside, and inside of these, a view pager that is filled with two fragments. the fragments are filled with data stored in an SQLite database in a loop.

The issue is that only the last viewpager adapter calls the getItem function, making that all cards are empty except the last one.

This is the element layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <com.jaimedediego.cubemaster.view.CustomViews.CustomViewPager
            android:id="@+id/detail_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The CustomViewPager works exactly like a normal viewpager.

This is the function where a external linear layout is filled with elements with the previous layout. Where timesDetail is filled with the data

```
        for (int i = 0; i < timesDetail.size(); i++) {
            final Detail detail = timesDetail.get(i);

            final View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.element_timesdetail_list, null);

            final CustomViewPager viewPager = v.findViewById(R.id.detail_container);

            viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
                @Override
                public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                    return PlaceholderFragmentDetail.newInstance(position, detail);
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    return 2;
                }
            });

            timesLayout.addView(v);
        }
    }
```

The getItem should be called for each loop to call the onCreateView of the PlaceholderFragmentDetail. but it doesn't (I think the issue is here). And it makes all cardview excepting the last one are empty.

The PlaceholderFragmentDetail call is

```
    public static class PlaceholderFragmentDetail extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        private static final String DETAIL = "detail";

        public PlaceholderFragmentDetail() {/*Do nothing*/}

        public static PlaceholderFragmentDetail newInstance(int sectionNumber, Detail detail) {
            PlaceholderFragmentDetail fragment = new PlaceholderFragmentDetail();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            args.putSerializable(DETAIL, detail);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v;
            Detail detail = (Detail) getArguments().getSerializable(DETAIL);

            switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
                case 0:
                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog_areyousure, container, false);
                    break;
                default:
                    v = null;
                    break;
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
```

I really think that the issue is the getItem call of the FragmentPagerAdapter, but i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

[image: This is the current screen]

Comment: What does the variable `timesLayout` point to? Is it the `LinearLayout` in the first code block of your question? What is each of the card views supposed to contain? Each cardview should contain a `viewpager`? Is `layout.element_timesdetail_list` the layout that contains the layout in the first code block of the question? One thing that you could try is not passing `null` to the `inflate` call inside the `for` loop (this sometimes messes up the `LayoutParams`). Also check with Layout Inspector to check that the views are in the expected parent.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector for info on the Layout Inspector.

Comment: @frozenkoi `TimesLayout` is the element where `layout.element_timesdetail_list` is added.
Each cardview contains a `viewPager` witch is filled with the `PlaceholderFragmentDetail`

Comment: Also I use null in inflater because I add the view later `timesLayout.addView(v);`. it is the same